# Adding the Rocketeer-Database plugin to a Laravel Package Rocketeer

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm guessing that it needs to be done differently since it is dependent on the package, and the directions after I install it (doesn't tell me how to) are to add it as a service provider like so:

```
'Rocketeer\Plugins\RocketeerDatabaseServiceProvider',
```

And there's a 'Plugins' directory within the Rocketeer package.

Has anyone installed a plugin for a package before? I would greatly appreciate the tip

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should get the plugin via Composer, add the provider to `app.php` (or `local/app.php` depending on whether you're requiring Rocketeer as a dev dependency or not) and that should be good. That being said, what Rocketeer version do you use? Because that particular plugin may just not be compatible with Rocketeer 2